# Authentication guard for login page redirection in angular 6?

Tags: angular, authentication

[image]

Here In Angular when I on login page that time my login url is `http://localhost:3000/login` and now I change without login like this `http://localhost:3000/base/dashboard (this is right url)` so without login it not redirects on dashboard page it is login on login page, but when I put wrong url without login like this `http://localhost:3000/defrtfg` but it redirects on `pageNotFoundComponent(see below screenshot)` but I want to redirect on login page when I not logged in how it is possible ?

Authgaurd.guard.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthguardGuard implements CanActivate{
constructor (private router : Router) {}

canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    if(localStorage.getItem('username')){  
       return true;
    }else{
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
 { path: 'login', component : LoginFormComponent },   
 { path : 'base', component : BaseComponent,canActivate : [AuthguardGuard],
 children: [
   { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },    
   { path: 'dashboard', component : DashboardComponent },
 ]},
  { path: '**', component : PageNotFoundComponent },   
];
```

Comment: You should change this `{ path: '**', component : PageNotFoundComponent },` to this `{ path: '**', component : LoginFormComponent }, `

Comment: @AbdulBasit it is not possible other way to resolve this ?, because PageNotFountComponent  I used when user change manually wrong url

Comment: you can add two routes of `**` one with `canActivate` and one without it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
{ path: '**', component : PageNotFoundComponent, canActivate : [AuthguardGuard]}
```